# When to Initialize the instance variable in Java, which way is better?

Tags: java, constructor

[image]

[image]

Which way is better to initialize the instance variable (children variable)? Initialize it in the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the array is constant (i.e. always 26), it doesn't matter when you initialize it. Initializing it in the constructor body will postpone the initialization a little (the instance variables initialization expressions take place before the constructor body is executed), but in the case of a constant length, it would make no difference.

If, on the other hand, the length of the array was passed as a parameter to the constructor, you would have to initialize it in the constructor body:

```
class TrieNode {
    private TrieNode[] children;
    public TrieNode (int len) {
        this.children = new TrieNode[len];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is not other constructor in class (other than default one), then any approach is fine.

But in case there are other constructors also and when used those constructor this variable won't be needed in any method of class, then possibly this class need a refactoring.

So no much difference in both approach and keeping it at class level declaration will keep the code cleaner and remove unnecessary default contractor declaration.

**Additional Info:**
Avoid using magic number such as 26 in code. Give it a logical name, so that other developer will understand why there will be only 26 children. And if that can be changed then consider using parameterized constructor to pass the size as input parameter.